# Можно ли пользоваться системой замещения слоев но не модулей а шаблона в Joomla 3.7?

Tags: joomla, joomla3

Можно ли в файле конфигурации шаблона `templateDetails.xml` указать настройки стиля таким образом, что бы можно было выбирать какой слой отображать в том или ином меню?

У нас есть система замещения в модулях и мы можем прописать такие например параметры

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="advanced">

            <field
                name="layout"
                type="modulelayout"
                label="JFIELD_ALT_LAYOUT_LABEL"
                description="JFIELD_ALT_MODULE_LAYOUT_DESC"
            />              

        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</config>
```

Что добавить модулю выпадающий список в настройки, где мы можем выбрать то или иное существующее в файловой системе представление (вьюху).
Можно ли что то подобное сделать с шаблоном (вернее со стилем шаблона) а не с модулем?

Comment: вы об этом, как пример,   https://www.joomshaper.com/blog/how-to-use-two-or-more-templates-in-one-joomla-site ?

Comment: Нет, в данной статье показывается как создавать стили с разными настройками. А я про то как на основе этих настроек выбирать для стиля свой php слой для рендеринга с максимальной гибкостью.